# Getting error in extension manager, Check Component Dependency & 2 php errors

Tags: magento-2.2.5

[image]

[image]

Trying to find solution from many days on google but nothing found helpful.

Comment: Try this for component dependency https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/System-Upgrade-conflicting-component-dependencies/m-p/28104#M88

Comment: Php settings check: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/fix-php-settings-check-error-in-magento-2-0-installation-on-localhost/

Comment: @Sukumar Gorai php.ini does not exist on the file system.

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /home/xyz/public_html/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php on line 272

Comment: You need to increase memory_limit.

Comment: How can I increase? php.ini is not exist in public_html but htaccess is available & memory size is -  php_value memory_limit 756M

Comment: Can you check it that from where php.ini is running or setting? You need to add phpinfo into the root from where you can check the php.ini path and also the local and master value for memory_limit etc.